# Detecting memory leaks

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

Consider the following code:

```cpp
int main(){
    A c;
    A array[5];
    A *ptr;
}
```

Assuming that class `A` has no memory leaks. Does the above code have any memory leaks?

**My thoughts**:

The variables `c` and `array` of these six objects of type `A` will get allocated/instantiated.

The `ptr` variable is not assigned anything, so that nothing will get created there.

For both `c` and `array`, before the program exits, the destructor for them will be called.

So, there should not be any memory leaks.

I am not sure of my reasoning above.

Also, will the memory for the `array` be allocated - **off the stack, off the heap, or in the global memory space?**

Comment: I think you are correct, the first one is stack-allocated and will be freed automatically (assuming that A has no memory leaks). The second one is basically the same just five times and the thirst one is just one local pointer which is always leak-free

Comment: Regarding your second question: As long as A does not allocate anything on the heap, everything will be stack allocated

Comment: A memory leak implies the existence of an object with dynamic storage duration to be leaked. Your example does not contain such an object.

Comment: The added question doesn't belong in this question, **but**: C++ doesn't know anything about stacks or heaps, but it'll probably end up on a stack.

Comment: Your reasoning is correct, just a hint when you start allocating memory and you do need pointers to A, then have a look at std::unique_ptr/std::make_unique. Unlike what is still in most books that is now the preferred approach.  (https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rr-owner)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no memory leaks as there are no mismatched

1. `malloc` / `free`
2. `new` / `delete`
3. `new[]` / `delete[]`

The array `array[5]` has *automatic storage duration*. That's the formal term for being "on the stack". Conceptually it goes out of scope at the closing brace `}` of `main()`, after `ptr` has gone out of scope.

Comment: Thanks. So does a memory is allocated on the heap only with the `new` operator? Also, is there a way to programmatically verify if something is on a heap or stack? Does the operating system know the difference between heap and stack, or it's just a logical separation or way of thinking?

Comment: "So does a memory is allocated on the heap only with the new operator" - with `auto a = new A`, `a` has *dynamic storage duration*.

Comment: "also, is there a way to programmatically verify if something is on a heap or stack", no there is not.

Comment: "Does the operating system know the difference between heap and stack" - it can be convenient to think in terms of a heap and a stack but note that those terms are not C++ language concepts but are rather to do with how C++ is implemented.

Comment: So that means this stack and heap are used internally in the implementation of the C++ language. Is that correct? Is there a good reference to read about it? Also, is C++ written in assembly language?

Comment: "So that means this stack and heap are used internally in the implementation of the C++ language" most likely yes.

Comment: "Also, is C++ written in assembly language?"  These days it's common for mainstream C++ compilers to be written in C++. They are able to compile themselves!